# Undefined array key "HTTP_USER_AGENT"

Tags: arrays, wordpress, http, key, undefined

Trying to solve an Undefined array key warning for "HTTP_USER_AGENT" for this line of code:

`if ( ( strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE' ) == false ) && ( $use_object_frame == true ) ) {`

Whole function:

`// Start widget output

```
     $title = apply_filters( 'widget_title', empty( $instance\['title'\] ) ? \_\_( 'Shopping Cart',      'wp-e-commerce' ) : $instance\['title'\] );
echo $before_widget;

    if ( $title )
        echo $before_title . $title . $fancy_collapser . $after_title;

    // Set display state
    $display_state = '';
    if ( ( ( isset( $_SESSION['slider_state'] ) && ( $_SESSION['slider_state'] == 0 ) ) || ( wpsc_cart_item_count() < 1 ) ) && ( get_option( 'show_sliding_cart' ) == 1 ) )
        $display_state = 'style="display: none;"';

    // Output start, if we are not allowed to save results ( WPSC_DONT_CACHE ) load the cart using ajax
    $use_object_frame = false;
    if ( WPSC_PAGE_CACHE_IN_USE  ) {
        echo '<div id="sliding_cart" class="shopping-cart-wrapper">';
        if ( ( strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE' ) == false ) && ( $use_object_frame == true ) ) {
            ?>
            <object codetype="text/html" type="text/html" data="index.php?wpsc_action=cart_html_page" border="0">
                <p><?php _e( 'Loading...', 'wp-e-commerce' ); ?></p>
            </object>
            <?php
        } else {
            ?>
            <div class="wpsc_cart_loading"><p><?php _e( 'Loading...', 'wp-e-commerce' ); ?></p></div>
            <?php
        }
        echo '</div>';
    } else {
        echo '<div id="sliding_cart" class="shopping-cart-wrapper" ' . $display_state . '>';
        include( wpsc_get_template_file_path( 'wpsc-cart_widget.php' ) );
        echo '</div>';
    }

    // End widget output
    echo $after_widget;

}`
```

Looked online for similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the "Undefined array key" warning.you can add a check for the existence of the "**HTTP_USER_AGENT**" key in the **$_SERVER** array before accessing it:

```
if ( array_key_exists('HTTP_USER_AGENT', $_SERVER) && ( strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE' ) == false ) && ( $use_object_frame == true ) ) {
//Your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks AR Riyad. Can I check that all you're suggesting is for us to change the following line of code and replace it with your suggested line of code? if ( ( strstr( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE' ) == false ) && ( $use_object_frame == true ) ) {